# Matching math between < > symbols

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to build a function that matches the math expression between two greater (or equal) or smaller (or equal) symbols.

I have the following preg_match function:

```
preg_match("/(<=?|>=?)(([0-9]|\+|\(|\))+)(<=?|>=?)/", "2<(2+2)<8", $matches);
```

When I read the $matches array I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <(2+2)<
    [1] => <
    [2] => (2+2)
    [3] => )
    [4] => <
)
```

Can anyone explain why the closing ) gets matched as part of the (2+2) and on it's own? I would like it to only match the whole (2+2).

Comment: You want to still capture the "less than"s? https://regex101.com/r/EW9s2X/1/, if not maybe https://regex101.com/r/EW9s2X/2/, look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: You also could simplify `(<=?|>=?)` to `[<>]=?` then you wouldn't even have capture groups there.

Comment: And `(?:[0-9]|\+|\(|\))+` to `[0-9+()]+`

Comment: @DmitryEgorov my thought as well, https://regex101.com/r/EW9s2X/3/ (I'd add that to your answer, looks much cleaner to me)

Comment: Thanks you chris85 and DmitryEgorov, that fixed my issue. I also agree that the simplification of the <> operators is a more elegant way or writing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've got two capturing groups for the expression between comparison signs:

```
(<=?|>=?)(([0-9]|\+|\(|\))+)(<=?|>=?)
         ^^              ^ ^
         |`----- $3 -----' |
         `------- $2 ------'
```

Change it to

```
(<=?|>=?)((?:[0-9]|\+|\(|\))+)(<=?|>=?)
           ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a quantified capture group `(...)+`

Each pass through the capture group, resets the capture group to empty.
The result is you only see the last capture.

You can see it below as `3 start/end`.

```
 ( <=? | >=? )                 # (1)
 (                             # (2 start)
      (                             # (3 start)
           [0-9] 
        |  \+
        |  \(
        |  \) 
      )+                            # (3 end)
 )                             # (2 end)
 ( <=? | >=? )                 # (4)
```

The individual pieces are of no use in this case,
changing it to a cluster group will exclude it from the output array.

```
 ( <=? | >=? )                 # (1)
 (                             # (2 start)
      (?:
           [0-9] 
        |  \+
        |  \(
        |  \) 
      )+
 )                             # (2 end)
 ( <=? | >=? )                 # (3)
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 7 ) 
<(2+2)<  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 1 ) 
<  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 1 , len 5 ) 
(2+2)  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 6 , len 1 ) 
<
```